# What is the degree of the field extension $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[4] 2,\sqrt[8] 2)$ over $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> What is the degree of the field extension $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[4] 2,\sqrt[8] 2)$ over $\mathbb Q$?

The options given are $4$, $8$, $14$, $32$. Which one is correct?

I think the answer is $8$. What I have done is to use the following
$$\begin{align}
[ \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[4] 2,\sqrt[8] 2) : \mathbb Q]
&=
[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[4] 2,\sqrt[8] 2) : \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[4] 2)] \cdot
[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[4] 2) : \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2) ]\cdot[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2) : \mathbb Q ].\end{align}$$ and conclude that each has a degree $2$ on the right hand side, thus total degree is $8$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\left(\sqrt[8]2\right)^2=\sqrt[4]2$$
and therefore
$$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[4] 2,\sqrt[8] 2)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt[8] 2)$$

Comment: i request you not to encourage this kind of questions with no effort shown....

Comment: My answer is a hint and not the solution. Some effort still needs to be done.

Comment: Yes Yes that is true...

Answer (score 8):

We have $\sqrt[4]{2}=(\sqrt[8]{2})^2$ and $\sqrt{2}=(\sqrt[4]{2})^2$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[8]{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2})$. Now, $\sqrt[8]{2}$ is a root of the polynomial $X^8-2$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ by Eisenstein's criterion and therefore also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Gauss's lemma, which shows that the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is indeed $8$.